# How to ensure two standalone documents have same dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, dimensions

I've made two `standalone` documents that ought to be the same dimensions (page size), but `pdfinfo` reports the page sizes (dimensions) as being slightly different, and I can't for the life of me see why. The two documents are supposed to be the front and back of a print.

The included graphics are commented out, since they do not impact the document dimensions, and for reproducibility.

Front: (pdfinfo reports a size of `481.89 x 340.157 pts`)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmvtt}
\usepackage[letterspace=120]{microtype}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[white] (-1,-1) rectangle (16,11);
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (15,10);
%\node at (3.5,9.4) {\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{logo.pdf}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Back: (pdfinfo reports a size of `482.687 x 340.556 pts`)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmvtt}
\usepackage[letterspace=120]{microtype}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{3c3475}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] (-1,-1) rectangle (16,11);
\draw[gray] (7.5,-1) rectangle (7.5,11);
%\node at (3.5,7) {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{dfp-logo.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could draw an invisible `rectangle` of the desired size and `use as bounding box`.

Comment: @Skillmon This was what I was trying to accomplish with `\fill[white] (-1,-1) rectangle (16,11);`

Comment: Put a `use as bounding box` in the options of that rectangle.

Comment: That works! If it was an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason can be seen from this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=1cm] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw [red] (0,0) -- (1,0);

\draw [blue,line cap=rect] (-0.5\pgflinewidth,0) -- (-0.5cm+0.5\pgflinewidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

The whitespace on the sides is, as you can see from the blue line, 0.5cm, so half the linewidth of the black line. Seems TikZ leaves room in the bounding box for a `rect` type `line cap`, even if the standard `butt` is used.

So in your examples, for the first you only have

```
\fill[white] (-1,-1) rectangle (16,11);
```

whereas in the second you also `\draw` paths to the edges of this rectangle. When you do e.g.

```
\draw[thick, white] (-1,-0.5) -- (16,-0.5);
```

this will therefore extend the bounding box by 0.4pt on both the left and right sides, as `thick` corresponds to `line width=0.8pt`. From `pdfinfo`, you see that the second one is about 0.8pt wider than the first one.

The 0.4pt difference in height comes similarly from

```
\draw[gray] (7.5,-1) rectangle (7.5,11);
```

which adds half the default line width, 0.4pt, at the top and bottom.

If you change the offending lines in the second diagram to

```
\draw[gray,line cap=rect] (7.5,-1cm+0.5\pgflinewidth) rectangle (7.5,11cm-0.5\pgflinewidth);
\draw[thick, white, line cap=rect] (-1cm+0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5) -- (16cm-0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5);
\draw[thick, white, line cap=rect] (-1cm+0.5\pgflinewidth,10.5) -- (16cm-0.5\pgflinewidth,10.5);
```

both PDFs become 481.89 x 340.157 pts according to `pdfinfo`.

Comment: Great explanation! This correctly identifies the problem with the code, and makes the `use as bounding box` option unnecessary. I change my accepted answer tot this, because I consider this solution less of a hack.

Comment: @martinmch I won't consider `use as bounding box` a hack. It is added to Ti*k*Z on purpose for cases similar like this (most notably if you need control points for a curve which might lie far outside your actual picture). Your acceptance of this answer above mine stays reasonable and valid though.

Comment: I agree that hack is the wrong word here.

Answer (score 7):

My comments as an answer:

You can tell Ti*k*Z that the desired size of the `tikzpicture` is the size of a single object in that `tikzpicture` with the option `use as bounding box`. Adding this option to your `\fill` rectangles in both pictures lead to 481.89 x 340.157 pts for both of them in `pdfinfo`.

Code for front:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmvtt}
\usepackage[letterspace=120]{microtype}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[white,use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (16,11);
\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (15,10);
%\node at (3.5,9.4) {\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{logo.pdf}};
\node at (5.8,9.12) {for};

%% Distance between each line should be changed from 0.03 to 0.04.
\draw[thick, densely dotted] (6.1,9.02) -- (13.5,9.02);
\draw[thick] (0.03,8.63) -- (14.97,8.63);
\draw[thin] (0.03,8.55) -- (14.97,8.55);
\draw[thick] (0.03,7.9) -- (14.97,7.9);

% Labels
\node at (0.5,8.225) {Tid};
\node at (2,8.19) {Mandag};
\node at (4,8.19) {Tirsdag};
\node at (6,8.19) {Onsdag};
\node at (9,8.19) {Torsdag};
\node at (11,8.19) {Fredag};
\node at (13,8.19) {L\o{}rdag};
\node at (14.5,8.225) {Tid};
\def\bordertext{Skole- og tegnemateriel, kollegiehefter etc.}
\node[rotate=-90] at (15.3,4.4) {\bordertext};
\node[rotate=90]  at (-0.3,4.4) {\bordertext};

\foreach \x in {1,3,5,7,8,10,12,14}{
    \def\topyone{8.53}; \def\lowyone{7.87};
    \def\topytwo{7.93}; \def\lowytwo{2.05}; % 0.03
    \ifthenelse{\x=1\OR\x=14}{
        \draw[thick] (\x,\topyone) -- (\x,\topytwo); % Top dividers
        \draw[thick] (\x,\lowyone) -- (\x,\lowytwo);  % Lower divider
    }{
        \draw[thin] (\x,\topyone) -- (\x,\topytwo); % Top dividers
        \draw[thin] (\x,\lowyone) -- (\x,\lowytwo); % Lower dividers
    }
}
% horizontal lines
\foreach \y in {7.25,6.6,5.95,5.30,4.65,4,3.35,2.7,2.05}{
       \draw[thin] (0.03, \y) -- (0.97, \y);
       \draw[thin] (1.03, \y) -- (2.97, \y);
       \draw[thin] (3.03, \y) -- (4.97, \y);
       \draw[thin] (5.03, \y) -- (6.97, \y);
       \draw[thin] (8.03, \y) -- (11.97,\y);
       \draw[thin] (12.03,\y) -- (13.97,\y);
       \draw[thin] (14.03,\y) -- (14.97,\y);
       }
\draw[thick] (0.03,2.05) -- (14.97,2.05);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Code for back:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmvtt}
\usepackage[letterspace=120]{microtype}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{3c3475}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue,use as bounding box] (-1,-1) rectangle (16,11);
\draw[gray] (7.5,-1) rectangle (7.5,11);
\draw[thick, white] (-1,-0.5) -- (16,-0.5);
\draw[thick, white] (-1,10.5) -- (16,10.5);
%\node at (3.5,7) {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{dfp-logo.pdf}};
%\node at (11.5,8) {\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{title.pdf}};
%\node at (11.7,1.5) {\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{nameplate-line-white.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing that I can add to Torbjørn T.'s great and accurate explanation. However, I'd like to mention that the creator(s) of Ti*k*Z provided an arguably simpler remedy of this issue: `pgfinterruptboundingbox`. You can easily confirm that, when using this in your this example the bounding box will not increase.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmvtt}
\usepackage[letterspace=120]{microtype}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{3c3475}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] (-1,-1) rectangle (16,11);
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\draw[gray] (7.5,-1) rectangle (7.5,11);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
%\node at (3.5,7) {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{dfp-logo.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that this trick is particularly handy in situations in which one creates auxiliary paths for, say, intersections.